# Image Email Attachment in Android doesn't open in right format

Tags: android, image, email

I've been trying since 2 hours, to find the code to email an image in Android. At least i was successful, but still have a problem. When i email the image, it opens as text file, and not as `jpeg`. I also used MIME type `(image/jpeg)`, but in vain. Please help me with this.

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("image/jpg");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,e2.getText().toString());
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,new String[]{e1.getText().toString()});
emailIntent.setType("image/jpg");
Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.mypackage.name/drawable/" + filename);
emailIntent.setType("image/jpg");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, path);
emailIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send Email"));
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Well, atlast i was successful! I had to copy the image to sdcard, and then attach it to the mail! It worked fine now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who need help, just copy the image to sdcard, and then attach! It works!

Comment: Hey what if i wanted to attach image from resource or asset folder as i want to attach app logo with email and keeping logo in SD card may create some copying issue. Help if you have any way to solve this.

Comment: Put it in a inner directory? Or an other alternative would be, after share is done, delete the image again?