# didnot support action_send email in android 4.0

Tags: android, android-intent, email-attachments

I have sent email via **ACTION_SEND** in android.

Here its successfully sent from *android 2.2*,but it is didn't sent from *android 4.1*.

I have used below code:

```
  ImageView share = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
  share.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    final CharSequence[] items = {"Facebook", "Twitter", "Email"};

  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SubCate.this);
  builder.setTitle("Share Via:");
  builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
   if(items[item] == "Facebook"){
        Intent in = new Intent(SubCate.this, TestConnect.class);
        in.putExtra("Title", _Substring); 
    startActivity(in);    
    } 
  if(items[item] == "Twitter"){
        Intent in = new Intent(SubCate.this, TestConnect.class);
        in.putExtra("Title", _Substring); 
     startActivity(in);    
   } 
   if(items[item] == "Email"){
           Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
           email.setType("message/rfc822");           
           email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ ""});           
           email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, _Substring);
           email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, _Description);
           email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ getPackageName() + "/" + R.drawable.ic_launcher));         
           startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));

         } 
          }
          }); 
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
  alert.show();
      }  
 });
```

Why these code is didn't work in *android 4.0* device.pls give me solution for these..

Here I have using alertlist dialog box.

I didn't use surface view anywhere.if i have remove these line

**email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ getPackageName() + "/" + R.drawable.ic_launcher));**

means its worked... the subject and text is sent to mail from android4.0...but i ahve facing problem only adding attach the image...pls give me solution.

Am getting following error:

```
        04-12 10:36:04.722: E/ViewRootImpl(1461): IllegalArgumentException locking surface
        04-12 10:36:04.722: E/ViewRootImpl(1461): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        04-12 10:36:04.722: E/ViewRootImpl(1461):   at android.view.Surface.lockCanvasNative(Native Method)
        04-12 10:36:04.722: E/ViewRootImpl(1461):   at android.view.Surface.lockCanvas(Surface.java:76)
        04-12 10:36:04.722: E/ViewRootImpl(1461):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:1924)
        04-12 10:36:04.722: E/ViewRootImpl(1461):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1613)
        04-12 10:36:04.722: E/ViewRootImpl(1461):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2418)
         04-12 10:36:04.722: E/ViewRootImpl(1461):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
         04-12 10:36:04.722: E/ViewRootImpl(1461):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
         04-12 10:36:04.722: E/ViewRootImpl(1461):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
         04-12 10:36:04.722: E/ViewRootImpl(1461):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
         04-12 10:36:04.722: E/ViewRootImpl(1461):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
         04-12 10:36:04.722: E/ViewRootImpl(1461):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
         04-12 10:36:04.722: E/ViewRootImpl(1461):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
         04-12 10:36:04.722: E/ViewRootImpl(1461):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**EDIT:**

```
    ImageView share = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
    share.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
      {
          public void onClick ( View v )
          {

            final CharSequence[] items =
            {
                    "Facebook", "Twitter", "Email"
              };

           AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
              builder.setTitle("Share Via:");
              builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
             {
                public void onClick ( DialogInterface dialog , int item )
                {

                    if (items[item] == "Facebook")
                    {

                        onFacebookClick();
                    }
                    if (items[item] == "Twitter")
                    {

                        onClickTwitt();
                    }
                    if (items[item] == "Email")
                    {
                        class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

                              protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                                   Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                   email.setType("message/rfc822");           

                        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]
                        {
                                ""
                        });
                        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, _Title);


                        email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(_Image));  
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));


                                return "Executed";
                          }      

                          protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                                       }

                          protected void onPreExecute() {
                          }

                          protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
                          }

                        }
                        }
                }
            });

              AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
              alert.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
              alert.show();
                  }
        });
    }
```

I have to run the app and click email means i didn't get anything...If i ahve to click facebook means facebook login is opening.But click email means i didn't get email compose message and didn't getting any error ??? Why ???  what's wrong in my code ...

Comment: Try out by writing your package name like `"android.resource://your.package.name/"` besides `getPackageName()` method.

Comment: @Grishu i have changed my code like :email.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ "com.xmlparsing" + "/" + R.drawable.ic_launcher));  but now also am getting same error only...

Comment: Try to take another image besides launcher image.

Comment: @Grishu hi i have used another image also.now also getting same error only...also this is worked on android 2.2 ...didn't working on android 4.0 ly...in android 4.0 have sent EXTRA_SUBJECT, EXTRA_TEXT....i have added EXTRA_STREAM means ly getting error...

Comment: I think you are using SurfaceView in your code somewhere. Can you post some more code ?

Comment: @Grishu i have added my code above...pls check it.here i didn't use surface view anywhere...

Comment: Have tried changing the `email.setType("image/png");` ?

Comment: Why you didn't specified any email id for sending the mail in `EXTRA_EMAIL` line . Please try to provide email address.

Comment: i have changed email.setType("image/png"); like above..also provided email id on that EXTRA_EMAIL...now also getting same error yar...

Comment: Post your whole activity code please if possible .

Comment: Check out my updated answer and try that way.

Answer (score 0):

This can be due to the reason that you cannot do network operation from the any UI activity in newer versions of android. Folow this link to make it work.

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

       Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
       email.setType("message/rfc822");           
       email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ ""});           
       email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, _Substring);
       email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, _Description);
       email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ getPackageName() + "/" + R.drawable.ic_launcher));         
       startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));

  }

        return "Executed";
  }      

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
               }

  @Override
  protected void onPreExecute() {
  }

  @Override
  protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to declare your String array as a global variable before `onCreate()` method. `final CharSequence[] items = {"Facebook", "Twitter", "Email"};`

Comment: @GrlsHu please check my updated question and Give me solution

Answer (score 0):

You use **droid share** for *sending email*.in droid share main part is **.setType**(for email you use **email/plain**).
Try this, I'm sure its works.

```
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
emailIntent.setType("email/plain");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "SUBJECT_TEXT");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "EXTRA_TEXT");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ getPackageName() + "/" + R.drawable.ic_launcher));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email using"));
```

Comment: you try to resolve your prob maybe from this link you get some idea. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22406  one test example also are there so, you its easy to understood for you.

Answer (score 0):

### **you have to copy your resource file in to sdcard after that attach in Email it work**

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6479253/1168654) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12975662/1168654) link for more detail.

**[copy resource to sdcard android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664468/copying-raw-file-into-sdcard)**

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below code on your Email item click.MAy it help you.Tt will send both image as well as text.You can send data as you want..

```
Bitmap bmp_cmpressed = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(edited_image, 60,
                60, false);
        File file_image = saveBitmap(bmp_cmpressed);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file_image);
        Intent mail_image = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        mail_image.setType("plain/text");
        mail_image.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                new String[] {});
        mail_image.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Image");
        mail_image.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        mail_image.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello...");
        Intent intent_mail = Intent.createChooser(mail_image, "Send Mail");
        startActivity(intent_mail);
```